# Facebook graph api feed permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am trying to create a Facebook app that needs to read the users News feed. In my app I use:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

I get 2 different results when I go to the direct link and via the app. I know that this is du to the permissions on my posts. My question is, what permission do i need to add in the `App->Settings->Permissions` so that the app will have full access to the feed posts?

I am using the PHP SDK if that changes anything. I call Graph like so:

```
$feed = $facebook->api('/me/feed', array('access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),'limit'=>200));
```

Thank you, and sorry for the noob question, I'm new to Facebook apps.

Comment: do you have the `read_stream` permission?

Comment: yes, I have `publish_stream read_stream & export_stream` just to sure

Comment: Then I guess this is the most you can get, please refer to this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/). Some posts on your wall may not be accessible by your app depending on privacy settings, I assume.

Comment: P.S.: you don't need to manually include the `access_token` to your api call as the PHP-SDK will add it for you.

Comment: When you say "different results", how many different results?  Also, you are missing limit=200 in the direct URL, which could explain it. When I try it on my test user, I get 84 feed stories for both 'direct' URL and $facebook->api()

Comment: when i do `$facebook->api()` i only get posts that are marked as Public. i tried switching a post from "Friends only" to "Public" and i saw it in the `$facebook->api()`. i guess what i'm asking is if there is a way to let my app see "Friends only" posts...

Comment: So strange.. Someone answered this question and I didn't get a change to try it... I think it was right, and it was deleted =\

Answer (score 0):

You need user_posts permission.

> Provides access to the posts on a person's Timeline. Includes their own posts, posts they are tagged in, and posts other people make on their Timeline.

And you can see it on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_posts